# MySQL query GROUPing from one table, excluding results found in another sub query

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, not-exists

Let's say I have two tables - ADDONS and DOWNLOADS.

ADDONS dictates which apps come with which addons for FREE.
DOWNLOADS logs addon downloads from all apps, those that include for free and not.

```
ADDONS  
appname  | varchar  
appaddon | varchar

DOWNLOADS  
id       | int  
appaddon | varchar  
appname  | varchar  
source   | varchar  
date     | datetime
```

I am trying to write a query that shows the count of each appaddon in DOWNLOADS where it was NOT included for free in ADDONS.

I got as far as:  `"SELECT appaddon, count(id) FROM downloads GROUP BY appaddon ORDER BY count(id) DESC"` - but that is inclusive of apps that included it for free and those that do not.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

---

Update:

Example:  Imagine I have two holiday themed apps - one for Christmas, one for Halloween, and each app allows you to download costumes that are included with the app (for example Halloween lets you download a witch, skeleton or jack o lantern, and Christmas lets you download a Santa or elf).  BUT if someone upgrades from within the app, they can download ANY of the available costumes (so Christmas upgraded could download a skeleton, or Halloween upgraded could download an Elf).

I am trying to get a count of the downloads that are NOT included without upgrading.  So I want to exclude the witches downloaded by Halloween, and the Santas downloaded by Christmas, but get a count of the witches, skeletons, elves, etc downloaded by the OTHER apps.

Here is some example data:

```
ADDONS  
appname     | appaddon  
========================  
halloween   | jackolantern  
halloween   | skeleton  
halloween   | witch  
christmas   | santa  
christmas   | elf  
christmas   | reindeer  
easter      | bunny  
allholidays | bunny

DOWNLOADS  
id | appaddon  | appname   | date  
=======================================
1  | skeleton  | halloween | 2012-10-15  
2  | skeleton  | halloween | 2012-10-15  
3  | witch     | halloween | 2012-10-16  
4  | santa     | christmas | 2012-10-16  
5  | elf       | christmas | 2012-10-16  
6  | witch     | christmas | 2012-10-16  
7  | bunny     | christmas | 2012-10-16  
8  | bunny     | halloween | 2012-10-17  
9  | bunny     | easter    | 2012-10-18
```

Based on above, I would expect the results:

```
appaddon  | count
=================
bunny     | 2
witch     | 1
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of your problem? I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding it. Perhaps you can use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and fill the tables with some data to make your problem easier for people to work on.

Comment: Sure - I updated with an example.

Comment: I figured it out - see my response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I figured it out!  Required me to use WHERE NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT appaddon, count(id) FROM DOWNLOADS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT appaddon FROM ADDONS
  WHERE DOWNLOADS.appname = ADDONS.appname
  AND DOWNLOADS.appaddon = ADDONS.appaddon)
GROUP BY appaddon
```

Fiddler for it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95988/4/0)

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT appaddon, count(id) FROM downloads 
    left join addons on addons.appname=downloads.appname
    where addons.appname is null
    GROUP BY downloads.appaddon ORDER BY count(id) DESC
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to work - I have added an example to my original post that might help.

Comment: It returns no results.  See updated post for expected results.

Comment: It was downloaded 3 times - 1 by Christmas, 1 by Halloween, and 1 by Easter.  According to the appaddon table, bunny is included by easter.  We are trying to count the number of downloads where it is NOT included, which would be 2 times (Christmas and Halloween)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```sql
SELECT DOWNLOADS.appaddon, COUNT(*) FROM DOWNLOADS
    INNER JOIN ADDONS ON (DOWNLOADS.appaddon = ADDONS.appaddon)
    WHERE DOWNLOADS.appname != ADDONS.appname
    GROUP BY DOWNLOADS.appaddon;
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle for it: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57e84/6)

Comment: Hello.  It works to a point, but then it breaks down as soon as I add a second app to the ADDONS table also connecting to one of the appaddons.  

For example: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95988/1/0)

Comment: I've updated the post with the additional record in ADDONS as that is a problem I keep running into with the real-world data the scenario is built on.

Comment: I think I figured it out - used a NOT EXISTS to get it.